# Execute classes with no entry point from within jar?

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I want to be able to execute arbitrary classes in the /bin directory of a jar file without unjarring.

I have been able to do this with a jar for Saxon by doing:

```
java -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -s:sax-tmp/courses.xml -o:q1.txt q1.xql
```

I honestly don't know why this works though. I can't find documentation of the cp flag and this command pattern hasn't worked for my project.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Answer (score 0):

It can not be any arbitrary classes. The class that can be executed has to have the method "public static void main(String[] args)" defined.

"-cp" or "-classpath" let you specify all the java classes that are needed for running the class with the main method (including this class).

Under the command line, if you type "java -?" you will see some explanations of the cp flag.

Comment: I have no trouble executing classes with a main method, until the output of javac goes to a /bin folder, then the trouble starts. I know how to add the jar to the classpath but syntax I showed doesn't work when the /bin gets involved.

Comment: @BretFontecchio, you should add the bin folder to the -cp as well. Something like java -cp /<path-to>/bin:other.jar. Change ":" to ";" if under windows

Comment: the bin is INSIDE the jar

Comment: Then i should suggest that bin folder should not be packaged in the jar unless "bin" is the top level package name